# Getting following error when tried to hit private endpoints on cex.io: "API key is not activated"

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I have created an API key in cex.io. When I try to hit private endpoints, it throws an error: "API key is not activated". 
I have 2FA activated via google authenticator.

I have went ahead and activated the key. Then also same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here. For some reason, cex doesnt like that you create API keys with 2FA enabled. Hence, follow the steps:

1. Disable 2FA.
2. Create API key
3. Activate API key
4. Enable 2FA.

Here is the response from cex.io support:

> To resolve this issue please disable your 2FA and try to activate API
>   - it should work. Please, don't forget to enable 2FA after this.